# REGEXP "and" operator

Tags: mysql, regex, operators

I have a database named "table" like this :

```
id  content
1     a
2     a b c
3     b a
4     c e a
```

and I want to get all the id where "a" and "c" are in content.

I know that I can find all the id where "a" or "c" are in content like this :

```
select id
from table
where content regexp 'a|c'
```

but I don't know what to use for "AND" operator

Comment: Can you give a more specific example?  This sounds like [an XY problem](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/XyProblem). That is, you may be better off doing things differently than the way you're trying to do them.

Comment: Mysql doesnt have native support to regex functions you have to find an UDF

Comment: Not sure if you should be using regexp for that. You could instead do `SELECT id FROM table WHERE content LIKE '%a%' AND content LIKE '%c%';`

Comment: @JorgeCampos: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/regexp.html

Comment: So as it support. Use this: (?=a)(?=c)

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using a regex for this, I would just use `LIKE`:

```
SELECT
    id
FROM
    `table`
WHERE
    content LIKE '%a%'
    AND content LIKE '%c%'
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use a pattern like this:

```
a.*c|c.*a
```

This matches an `a` followed by any number of characters and a `c` or a `c` followed by any number of characters and an `a`.

Alternatively, you could just chain two where clauses together:

```
select id
from table
where content regexp 'a' AND
      content regexp 'c'
```

Comment: Thanks but the idea is to use php to give the content of the regular expression. So i would need a query with a variable number of expression to look for